# CSS property "text-indent" not working with html span element

Tags: html, css

For example:-

HTML Code

```
<div>
     <h1><span class="title-icon">icon</span> Hello India!</h1>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
h1{
}

h1 span{
    background: url("../images/icon.png")
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    margin-right:1em;
}
```

Comment: Use an `<img>` with an alt attribute, not a span with a background image for this. The icon isn't decorative.

Comment: Use any element with block display instead of a span, or change the spans default display.

Comment: While I've given an answer that should do the trick for you, @Quentin's comment is correct; this is a case where an `<img>` tag is more appropriate.

Comment: style="display: inline-block;  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;" worked for me

Comment: @Quentin How would that icon not be decorative?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`text-indent` doesn't work on `inline` elements. `<span>` defaults to being `inline`. You need to change it so it works as an inline block:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 7):

Try setting `font-size` to `zero`:

```
h1 span {
    background: url("../images/icon.png")
    font-size: 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was with text-align. In case you modify align mode of the element or parent element(s) wrapping it to left, you must give a negative index for text-indent. Otherwise you must give a positive value.

```
.case1{text-indent:-999px;text-align:left;overflow:hidden;display:block}
```

Otherwise

```
.case2{text-indent:999px;text-align:right;overflow:hidden;display:block}
```